# Schubert calculus and number of lines satisfying some properties.

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, representation-theory, schubert-calculus

I am reading [the file](https://www.google.com.hk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CBsQFjAAahUKEwi4qszr-aLHAhXFjo4KHVIcAWg&url=%68%74%74%70%73%3a%2f%2f%69%63%65%72%6d%2e%62%72%6f%77%6e%2e%65%64%75%2f%6d%61%74%65%72%69%61%6c%73%2f%53%6c%69%64%65%73%2f%73%70%2d%73%31%33%2d%6f%66%66%5f%77%65%65%6b%73%2f%53%63%68%75%62%65%72%74%5f%76%61%72%69%65%74%69%65%73%5f%61%6e%64%5f%53%63%68%75%62%65%72%74%5f%63%61%6c%63%75%6c%75%73%5f%5d%5f%53%61%72%61%5f%42%69%6c%6c%65%79%2c%5f%55%6e%69%76%65%72%73%69%74%79%5f%6f%66%5f%57%61%73%68%69%6e%67%74%6f%6e%2e%70%64%66&ei=YuzKVbjxIsWdugTSuITABg&usg=AFQjCNEhhntlrQvyl3bEsCFbiJydsBrw7w&sig2=OzD0ESGxp-jPuD3krUnYBA&bvm=bv.99804247,d.c2E). I have a question on pae 18. It is said that: Given a line in $\mathbb{R}^3$, the family of lines intersecting it can be interpreted in $G(2, 4)$ as the Schubert variety
$$
X_{\{2,4\}}=\overline{\left(\begin{matrix} 
* & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
* & 0 & * & 1
\end{matrix}\right)}
$$
with respect to a suitably chosen basis determined by the line.

Why the family of lines is $X_{\{2,4\}}$? Thank you very much.

Comment: I have exactly the same question. Thanks for asking!